# Displaying data entered in one form to another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I want another form to display the selected items from the listbox of one form to rich text box of another form that opens up on button click. I used the following snippet in form 1 to display the content in message box, but now i want it another form. Need help...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace cities
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
               message.Append(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("You selected: \n" +message.ToString());         


        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471514/referencing-control-on-one-form-from-another-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following code to achieve what I wanted. And its doing just fine! :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace cities
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();


            foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
               message.Append(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Your Selected Cities :\n" + message.ToString() + "\n");

            Form2 childForm = new Form2();
            childForm.Controls["richTextBox1"].Text = message.ToString();
            childForm.Show();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't go with this method. A Form object is like any other Class. Simply build a constructor for your Form2 that takes the string object you wish to pass, like in the example by @Akshay Joy.

Comment: @derek Why not? Any specific reason?

Comment: Its not best practice to be accessing controls from one form from within another.

Answer (score 1):

From the First come just call the Second form like this

```
Form2 ob = new Form2(message);
ob.show();
```

This is the 2 nd form to set the Messge

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            public Form2(String message)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                richTextBox1.Text = message;
            }

            private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a public property in form1 which returns a string in the get, compose the string with the same logic you are using for the loop and string builder.

When you open form2 call a method of form2 which accepts a string, like SetMessage and pass form1.Message to that method you have created.

This is a way to get what you need without making the forms to depend on their internal controls, so it does not break if you replace controls as long as you edit only a couple of methods/properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the second `form` create a method:

```
public void SetRichTextboxText(string text)
{
     richTextBox1.Text = text;
}
```

then in your first form add this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

     foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
     {
          message.Append(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
     }

     var form = new Form2();
     form.SetRichTextboxText(message.ToString());
     form.Show(this);
}
```

Comment: You should be setting the text through a delegate invoked by the UI thread. You shouldn't access UI elements on a non-UI thread of that form.

Comment: It's bad practice. You don't know that will be the case.

Comment: It is not a bad practice. If you are creating multi-threaded application, make delegates if not, then don't. There is no reason to move that logic to other thread.

Comment: It still doesnt display the slected items in the rich text box in 2nd form. where am I  going wrong?

Comment: Put some breakpoints and see what is passed to `SetRichTextboxText`, also can you show your second `form` logic? :)

Comment: public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void SetRichTextboxText(string text)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }

Comment: I do not see any problems with your code, have you tried putting breakpoint and see what happens (check if message is not empty especially).

Answer (score 0):

In the Form 2, you have to add a property of the message for the richtextbox:

```
private string _message = string.Empty;
    public string message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value; }
    }
```

In the form 1:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
           message.Append(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
        objForm2.message = message.ToString();
        objForm2.ShowDialog();
```

}

In form 2 page load:

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = message;
    }
```