# Accessing one from another form, is it because it is a reference?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a tabControl in form 1 named tbControl.
When i press a button for example, i like to change the index of this tabControl with :

```
this.tbControl.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

It works.

Then I have a form 2, in which i have done this :

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

Then i try to do this for example :

```
form1.tbControl.SelectedIndex=1;
```

But it doesn't work, the tabControl doesn't change the index.
Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing control on one form from another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471514/referencing-control-on-one-form-from-another-form)

Comment: This question is already answered here many times. You just need to search first

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the `SelectedIndex` on an unshown `new Form1`.  You likely want to change the `SelectedIndex` on an already existing `Form1`, so you'll need to find a way to pass it into your other form.  Some psuedo-code:

```
class Form1
{
    private void onShowForm2()
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.MainForm = this;
        f2.Show();
    }
}

class Form2
{
    public Form1 MainForm { get; set; }
    private void DoStuff()
    {
        //Change selected index on passed in instance of Form1
        MainForm.tbControl.SelectedIndex=1;
    }

}
```